# Authentication error in Heroku pip install my private repo

Tags: personal-access-token

I'm trying to push my Django app to heroku, and gets Authentication error when installing my
private repo from github.

I've generated Personal Access Token and added it to my Environment Variables as GITHUB_TOKEN.

I've tried many combinations in my requirements.txt:

package_name @ git+https://$dviralfi:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/dviralfi/package_name.git

package_name  @ git+https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/dviralfi/package_name.git

package_name  @ git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/dviralfi/package_name.git

None of them is working.

I get all sort of errors:

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote:          remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
remote:          fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/dviralfi/package_name.git/'

fatal: could not read Password for 'https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com': No such device or address